# what is a root directory in IIS 6 and How do I make one of my subfolder in ASP.NET website the root directory?

Tags: asp.net, web, iis-6, root

I need to integrate a third party plugin in my asp.net website. To install the plugin, they have mentioned this sentence, "Create an application through your IIS control panel with root directory at -(some path from my website folder)?".

I am not much aware with IIS and rarely worked with it. Though I tried every possible way I could do in IIS, I am not able to work it out. After installation, there is a test page provided by plugin which I have to run to check but when I run it, it shows this error.

"It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS."

I searched this error too and found that it is because the two Web.Config file, one from the main project and another from plugin folder. The only way to work with this, is to make the plugin folder they specified as a root directory in IIS. Someone kindly tell me some easy steps to do this. 
What I was doing is, in IIS6, I added New website with the main folder of my asp.net website, then I right click>add application and choose the given path, thought it would become root directory but it is not.

Help would be appreciated. Also note that, I have to put the plugin folder in my main website folder only. So, there are two web.config. I tried to rename one of them too, it solved the above error but gave another errors but I think main problem is of root directory. P.S they show me above error on web.config file of plugin folder on this sentence-

"Line 51:

```
< authentication mode="Windows" />"
```

Answer (score 4):

Most of the times the root directory is C:\inetpub\wwwroot folder and "Default Web Site" on IIS Manager.

Open IIS Manager and under Sites there should be IIS websites and under it you will probably see Default website. You can see the root directory with Right click/Settings.
Copy your website files under this root directory.
And after copying folder to root folder you will see this folder under Default websites on IIS.
Right click your directory name on IIS and "Create Application", select correct .net framework.
It should be work. Good luck, if you need more help please give more details on your server IIS.

Comment: hey thanks. But unfortunately I deleted that default website from IIS. so now?

Comment: Are there any other websites on IIS? If not you should create a new website, then you can install the software on it.